# How to convert an INI file into an CSV file

Tags: python, bash, csv, export-to-csv, ini

I would like to create a csv from a list of data, but the key values differ between sections of the list. The list is of the following layout:

```
[Game 1]
Publisher=
Developer=
Released=Nov, 2005
Systems=
Genre=Action|Strategy
Perspective=3rd-Person Perspective
Score=4.5
Controls=
Players=
Rating=
Url=http://www.google.com.pl
Description=This cartridge contains six of the 1 kilobyte e......

[Game 2]
Publisher=Home Entertainment Suppliers Pty. Ltd.
Developer=Imagic
Released=1992
Systems=
Genre=Action
Perspective=3rd-Person Perspective
Score=1.5
Controls=Joystick (Digital)|Same/Split-Screen Multiplayer
Players=1-2 Players
Rating=
Url=http://www.google.com
Description=An unlicensed multi-cart from the Australian-bas.....
Goodname=2 Pak Special - Alien Force & Hoppy
NoIntro=
Tosec=2 Pak Special Light Green - Hoppy & Alien Force
```

[Full file here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22410524/Atari%202600.ini)

Each set of data is separated by [Game *] and the values presented for each game can be blank or non existent for some games, eg Goodname=, NoIntro= and Tosec= are missing from Game 1. I don't know the total number of keys/columns required. Ideally I would like each game on a separate line in the csv file.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this format of data into a csv? I'm stumped. I'm familiar with bash and python but I'm open to any suggestions of how to automate the conversion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would use python, would be easier parsing the config. Use [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) to parse your file. For each section create an entry using the [CSV Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and leave value empty for non-existent values, `Game 1,,,"Nov, 2005", ...`

Comment: PHP can also do this with [`parse_ini_file()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python you can use the [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) library for reading the [INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) and the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library for writing a comma separated file. I wrote below a small script `ini2csv.py` that you can use to handle your conversion using the following command:

```
cat atari.ini | ./ini2csv.py > atari.csv
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# encoding: utf-8

import sys
import csv
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

ini = ConfigParser()
ini.readfp(sys.stdin)

#Find all keys in the INI file to build a row template and 
#include a "game" field to store the section name.
rowTemplate = {"game":""} 
for sec in ini.sections():
   for key,value in ini.items(sec):
       rowTemplate[key] = "" 

#Write the CSV file to stdout with all fields in the first line
out = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
out = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, fieldnames=rowTemplate.keys())
out.writeheader()

#Write all rows
for sec in ini.sections():
   row = rowTemplate.copy()
   row["game"] = sec
   for key,value in ini.items(sec):
       row[key] = value
   out.writerow(row)
```

I tested it with the link you provided in your question and it appears to work as expected.

Comment: Works fine. In python3, the modulename is lowercase: `from configparser import ConfigParser`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need verbose python? Perl goes quicker...

```
 # vi ini2csv.pl 
 #! /usr/bin/perl
 my $c = "None" ;                   # $c is current category
 while(<>) {                        # parse diamond operator (STDIN+...)
   next if m/^[;\#]/ || m/^$/ ;     # skip comments and empty lines
   if (m/^\[([^\[])\]/) { $c = $1 } # switch current category 
   else { "$c\t$_"; }               # print with tabulation
 }
```

This script is used as follows, this outputs a CSV file.

```
 $ cat atari.ini | ini2csv.pl
```

Comment: This answer lacks an explanation of how the script should be applied. Someone without Perl knowledge can do pretty much nothing with it. I'd say it's nerd flexing rather than an answer, even if it worked. I also think this script will not output any csv table but just prefix the rows with their category, so this is not an answer to the question.